# Unable to run command in codeception

Tags: selenium, cmd, codeception

I am trying to run this command through CMD can you please tell me whats wrong I am typing?

codecept.phar Run C:\Documents\Testportal\TestPortal\Loginlogout.phar

Error I am getting is 'PHP' is not recognised as an internal or external command,operable file or Batch File

Comment: Windows? What output from `where "PHP"` CLI command? Maybe `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)`?

Comment: What version of php you see when you run `php -v` in cmd?

Comment: @Madhumita, do you can put the full test and error log when run codecption?

Answer (score 0):

Seem you've just installed php on your machine. So, you should define your Environment Path to include the installed PHP folder path to make .php file become executable in command line.